# Why I am getting output 0 while running this code

Tags: python-3.x

When I run this code, it gives 0 as output
But I am calling func(a). Why it is not
not assigning 1 to a

```
a = 0
def func(x):
    x = 1
func(a)
print(a)
```

Comment: I think you would find the answer to your question in this previous SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference

Comment: @pastaleg, In that case, shoot a close vote.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are making a local variable in the function, ideally what you should be doing is this.

```
a = 0
def func():
    global a
    a = 1
func()
print(a)
```

Comment: To avoid using a global: `def func(): return 1` then `a = func()`.